# making a custom login in auth0 to authenticate using a rest API call

Tags: rest, authentication, auth0

I want to make a custom login page using auth0 (where I can modify the default fields required for login)
and validate the credential by requesting a rest API.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on auth0 and found a fix.

**Note: this may not be the exact method to make a custom login page but it worked for me.**

Here are the steps to be followed to design a custom login in auth0.

**Step 1:** If you need to change some fields required during login, Go to *Hosted Pages* in auth0 console. Otherwise, directly go to Step 4.

**Step 2**: Under the *login* tab, switch to *Customize Login Page* and then set *Custom Login Form* from the *Default Templates* dropdown.

**Step 3**: Here you need to edit the code to modify the fields. 
After editing in the script, make sure to set the `databaseConnection` name to your custom Connection you are using.

```
// var databaseConnection = 'Username-Password-Authentication';
// change this to
var databaseConnection = 'your-connection-name';
```

**Step 4:** After doing this, head over to your custom database connection in the auth0 console. Go under *Custom Database* tab and switch to *Use my own database*.

**Step 5:** Under the *login* tab, select *Request with basic Auth* in the *Templates* dropdown.

**Step 6:** Now you can edit the login function and request the rest API.